# Class<T> and static Class, Best Practices?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static, constants, generic-type-argument

I have a scenario that (simplified) is as follows:

```
public static class Example
{
    public const int CONSTANT_VALUE = 1;

    public static Example<T> Create<T>(IEnumerable<T> argument)
        where T : class
    {
        return new Example<T>(argument);
    }

    //More overloads of Create<T>, possibly other static methods, etc..
}

public class Example<T>
    where T : class
{
    public Example(IEnumerable<T> argument)
    {
        //Do Stuff

        //Nothing like this in the real code, just example
        //that constants are used from the other class.
        if (something == Example.CONSTANT_VALUE)             
        {
            //Do A Thing
        }
    }

    //Lots more code
}
```

The basic idea is that I can have static methods, constants, etc. available through the name of the class through the static class, while the actual implementation is in the type-argumented non-static class.

My question is whether or not this is a good way to set this up. Is there a way to put some static methods and constants that don't care what the type argument is on `Example<T>`? Is there otherwise a more recommended pattern? What I have works fine, but I wanted to know if there are other ways since this is the first time I've ended up doing something like this (not that it's conceptually new to me, just never had need).

Comment: Well, does your type parameter apply to the whole class (i.e. all methods), or does it make sense just to have it apply to one method?

Comment: It applies to the whole class as the main purpose of the class (in my case) is to encapsulate a collection and provide ways of working with it and its contents (returning T, mostly, for actual use of the parameter). In the real code my class derives from CollectionView and implements ICollectionView and the static class converts incoming data into formats that are friendly for input into the type-argumented class, has a constant in it, and will probably be extended with more static variables/methods as-needed.

Comment: `Tuple` does the same: `Tuple.Create(123, 456)` returns a `Tuple<int, int>`. :)

Comment: @Caramiriel - Yeah I thought there were Microsoft examples of this same pattern, I guess that confirms that it's a valid pattern in at least some cases. For others' reference, here's the reference source for Tuple, and it is indeed the same pattern: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only make sense if the constants are public. If they are only for internal use inside `Example<T>` then this is pointless, becuase you can reference them without a fully qualified name.

If the constants are of public use, I wouldn't use this pattern anayways; `Example` and `Example<T>` are two different classes, it is potentially confusing to any user, and not immeadiately obvious, that constants defined in the non generic class are aplicable to the generic one.

You are only avoding the user a few keystrokes, I'm not really sure it is worth it.

**Update: other options**

In this scenario, I'd use the following factory pattern (assuming the users are outside your assembly)

```
public class Example<T>
{
     internal Example() { } //disallow users from instantiating this class
      ...
}

public static class Example
{
    public const int Constant = ...
    public static Example<T> Create<T>() { return new ... }
}
```

And now all users will interact only with `Example` and avoid using `Example<T>`. You could even enforce this with users of your own assembly, you'd just need to make `Example<T>` a private nested class implementing a public interface:

```
 public interface IExample<T>
 {
     ...
 }

 public static class Example
 {
     private class Example<T>: IExample<T> { ... }
     public static IExample<T> Create<T>() { ... }
     ....
  }
```

Comment: The constant is used by `Example` and `Example<T>`, shared between them. I see your point when saying it could confuse a user, but it could just as easily be called something that makes it clearer without changing the pattern, so I don't think that should affect the decision to use said pattern.

Comment: I like this (the second option, with the public interface) - a lot - I've implemented it this way and am selecting this as an answer. For the record, the pattern I initially implemented is perfectly valid, but only necessary when the Example<T> needs to also be accessible - this is a little neater and more self-documenting, which is more than enough reason to switch to it when you're trying to write well-documented and comprehensible code (which I am trying very hard to do).

Answer (score -1):

Unless there is a reason this wouldn't work in your case, I would prefer to use a non-static base class `Example`, and then let `Example<T>` inherit from this class. That way you get direct access to all the methods in `Example`, without having to qualify with the name. Of course, this assumes that the `Example` class is exclusively to be used in connection with the various typed classes `Example<T>`.

Comment: It wouldn't work in my case because Example<T> already inherits from a base class (which I don't control), so it can't inherit from another. This is a good alternative for situations where that isn't the case, though.

Comment: That doesn't mean it won't work - unless that other base class also is generic, you can just let the untyped `Example` class inherit from that base class.

Comment: I think you're right, yeah. I didn't downvote you, btw - someone else did.